# Proof that $A\in M_{n\times n}\mathbb{R}$ is a permutation matrix if and only if it is the product of elementary matrices of type $P_{ij}$.

Tags: matrices, permutations, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank, permutation-matrices

We define a permutation matrix $A\in M_{n\times n}\mathbb{R}$ as a matrix that has all its coefficients 0 except from a 1 in each row and each column. Then, proof that $A\in M_{n\times n}\mathbb{R}$ is a permutation matrix if and only if it is the product of elementary matrices of type $P_{ij}$.

Comment: This amounts to say that a permutation is the product of transpositions...

Comment: Maybe it can help you that every invertible matrix is the product of elementary matrices (for example notice that if $A$ is invertible, then it is $A^{-1}$. Then apply Gaussian elimination and you will obtain the identity matrix. That means that $QA^{-1}=I_n$ for a certain matrix $Q=E_1\dots E_k$, hence $A=Q=E_1\dots E_k$. I have used the fact that row reduction is the equivalent of multiplying to the left for elementary matrices). Also a permutation matrix is obtained by permuting the columns of the identity matrix, which is a Gauss operation.

Answer (score 0):

I would answer this way. First, show that the set $S$ of permutation matrices is a subgroup of $GL_n$ (it is not hard to prove it). Then, for $M \in S$, let $\sigma$ be the unique permutation on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $M_{i,j} = \delta_{i,\sigma(j)}$ where $\delta$ stands for the Kronecker symbol. You can show $\sigma$ exists by constructing it : $\sigma(j)$ is the rank of the only line for which there is a $1$ at the $j$-th place. Now, show that $M \in S \mapsto \sigma \in\mathfrak{S}_n$ is a group homomorphism. It is surjective (as you can construct the desired matrix for a chosen $\sigma$ by the formula above) and for cardinality reasons, it will be an isomorphism. Thus, the results is the same as saying that $\mathfrak{S}_n$ is generated by transpositions, which is true.